# Where did Ross sleep?

Tags: friends

In *[Friends](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friends)*, when Ross moved in with Chandler and Joey, where was he sleeping? The apartment only had two rooms. Did he share a room with one of them?

Comment: Good question. There was a couch, but IIRC he brought a lot of stuff. I'm not sure this was ever explained.

Comment: Probably on the sofa that he and Joey used to nap on.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This attractive floorplan, lovingly drawn by interior design expert [Inaki Aliste Lizarralde](https://www.fastcocreate.com/1682531/an-interior-designer-explains-the-unlikely-apartments-of-friends-how-i-met-your-mother-and-m#4) shows that unless Ross is sharing a bed with Chandler (or sleeping in the bath), there's literally no place he could be sleeping other than the couch.

[image: apartment map and living room screenshot]

And if he *was* sleeping in the bath or with Chandler, it seems likely that it would have been mentioned at least once.

Comment: The building had a substantial storage basement. It seems likely that after the "moving in" episode, he stashed the larger items (and spare boxes) in there.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a screenshot of the pillows and blanket on the yellow couch, so I'm sure Ross used the yellow couch.

[image: pillow on yellow couch]

Answer (score -1):

The couch does seem like the obvious place at first, *but let's not forget that you can sleep on a recliner.*

Sleeping in the bathroom is a very unlikely thing for Ross to do, specifically because we know that he is a clean and neat person, so the bathroom would be unsanitary for him to sleep in.

It is mentioned that along with the tons of stuff he brought with him, were things that other people would not consider a must have, such as an air purifier that Joey and Chandler make fun of.

With all that being said, and with Ross being the prepared and structured type of person, it is possible that he had an air mattress with him that he set up in the living room.

Answer (score -1):

I believe he slept on the couch, because when Joey and Chandler sat down and talked about how they feel bad wanting to kick Ross out, you can see 2 blankets and a pillow resting on the arm chair in preparation for the night.

this is from the episode "The One Where Ross Moves In"

Comment: Hello and Welcome to Movie & TV Stack Exchange! While your answer seems helpful, it would benefit greatly by providing a source such as a screencap, clip, or episode number. :)